# Duplicating a polygon and offsetting it by distance and bearing from the original polygon

Tags: qgis

I am trying to locate a historical distribution/denning point for a species with the data "35km NW of x", with x being a small town. I have created a rough polygon around the current extent of the town using a satellite image. To define my search area I therefore have to duplicate the polygon and then off-set it from the original according to the bearing and distance.

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. Unfortunately,  questions here not only need to state the goal, they also should describe what you have attempted to accomplish that goal. Coding questions are expected to contain code. Please  [edit] the question to state what you have attempted.

Comment: Given that there are 2 answers which both address the problem, I think it's quite clear what's being asked.

Comment: I would expect the term "NW" might not be as specific as a direction of exactly 315 degrees. So you might want to look at wider a range of directions, say from 300 to 330 degrees.

Comment: I used the advanced digitizing tool which worked well (once I figured out I had to convert the CRS to a geographical system in order for advanced digitizing to be switched on). Thanks all for the advice and tips.

Answer (score 4):

With QGIS 3.2 and onwards it is possible to use the advanced digitizing tools that allow specifying an angle and a distance for the move tool.

There is a [youtube video with detailed instructions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EXmdiDAUXZI).

Answer (score 3):

**QGIS 3.0**

**Geometry by expression** tool (in `Processing Toolbox | Vector geometry`) would be useful.

(1) Select and highlight your polygon, and activate this tool.

(2) Expression (big epsilon icon):

```
translate( $geometry,  cos(radians(135))*35000,  sin(radians(135))*35000)
```

[image]

Please note the angle is measured from East, counter-clockwise.